# Data Ingestion from Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce-marketing-cloud, aws-glue-workflow

**My requirement:** I want to ingest data from salesforce marketing cloud to amazon s3 using amazon glue workflow and job, and schedule the job to run every hour,to get all the objects/fields from Salesforce Marketing Cloud to my Amazon S3 Bucket for data further data analysis. I am looking for open source ways and the best approach using aws glue job.

Comment: this should help https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/extracting-salesforce-com-data-using-aws-glue-and-analyzing-with-amazon-athena/

Comment: I tried and followed same example, I am getting INVALID_LOGIN as error. I checked and verified credentials everything is correct.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy - you are referring to an integration with Sales Cloud, while OP needs to integrate S3 with Marketing Cloud